# NameError in Messages#index for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a custom inbox and after I added this line to get all messages to show, "<% user.received_messages.each do |message| %>" I now am getting a "undefined local variable or method `user' " error. Not sure why that extra line of coding is causing this error and how to fix it.

_inbox.html:

```
<h2>Your Inbox</h2>
<% user.received_messages.each do |message| %>
No messages in your Inbox
<% end %>
        <%= form_tag delete_multiple_user_messages_path, :method=>:post do %>
            <table  class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Delete?</th>
                    <th>Sent</th>
                    <th>Sender</th>
                    <th>Sent</th>
                </tr>
                    <% for message in @messages %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= check_box_tag "delete[]", message.id %></td>
                            <td>
                                <% if message.read? %>
                                  <%= link_to h(message.subject), user_message_path(@user, message) %>
                                <% else %>
                                  <%= link_to "#{h(message.subject)} (unread)", user_message_path(@user, message) %>
                                <% end %>
                            </td>
                            <td><%= "#{message.sender.first_name} #{message.sender.last_name}" %></td>
                            <td><%=h message.created_at.to_s(:long) %></td>
                        </tr>
            <% end %>
            </table>
        <%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %> |
        <% end %>
<%= link_to "Compose New Message", new_user_message_path(@user)%> | 
<%= link_to "View Sent Messages", user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox => :sent)%>
```

index.html:

```
<% if params[:mailbox] == "sent" %>
        <%= render :partial => "sent" %>
<% elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox" %>
        <%= render :partial => "inbox" %>
<% elsif params[:mailbox] == "archieved" %>
        <%= render :partial => "inbox" %>
<% end %>
```

messages_controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_user

  def index
    if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = @user.sent_messages
    elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox"
      @messages = @user.received_messages
    #elsif params[:mailbox] == "archieved"
     # @messages = @user.archived_messages
    end
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
    if params[:reply_to]
      @reply_to = User.find_by_user_id(params[:reply_to])
      unless @reply_to.nil?
        @message.recepient_id = @reply_to.user_id
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.sender_id = @user_id
    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent"
      redirect_to user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox=>:inbox)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @message = Message.readingmessage(params[:id],@user_id)
  end

  def delete_multiple
      if params[:delete]
        params[:delete].each { |id|
          @message = Message.find(id)
          @message.mark_message_deleted(@message.id,@user_id) unless @message.nil?
        }
        flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
      end
      redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = current_user
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have no helper method named `user`. Maybe you have `current_user` or instance variable `@user` in `Messages` controller?

**UPDATE**

Maybe you wish to pass `user` variable to partial? Then you need to alter `render` call to something like this: `<%= render :partial => "inbox", :user => some_user_instance %>`

Comment: I have def set user. Added controller to original post.

Comment: so, you need to use @user to make it work. Anyway, see my update too